# apache htaccess rewrite rules make redirection loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Have a very strange problem with Apache .htaccess URL Rewriting and Redirection. Here's my setup: 
I have a zend application with a single point of entry (index.php) directly under my apache document root (call this the "public" folder). I also have all other public files (images, js, css, etc.) under the public folder. Here, I also have a wordpress blog under the "blog" folder. There's an empty test folder too

**The Problem**

When I go to example.com/blog, I get redirected to http://www.example.com/blog (correctly), then to http://www.example.com/blog/ (just with an extra / at end), finally to http://example.com/blog/ -- and we're back where we started. The loop continues. What I don't understand is why would wordpress try to remove the www? I'm guessing it's wordpress because my empty test folder acts just fine!

Another weird this is that I can actually go to www.example.com/blog/wp-login.php or example.com/blog/wp-login.php and it actually LOADS UP!!!!!

PLEASE HELP. I"M REALLY DESPERATE :( Thank you very much

Other things that happen:

When I go to example.com, i correctly get redirected to www.example.com

When I go to www.example.com, i correctly stay where I am

When I go to www.example.com/test or example.com/test, behaviour is correct.

**Setup**

So my .htaccess file does the following:

- If there's no www., then add it and do a 301 redirect. Here's the code I use

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]`

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

- If the request is NOT for a resource (image, etc.), or the blog, then load zend application by rewriting to index.php

`RewriteRule !((^blog(/)?.*$)|(.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|cur|JPG|html|txt))$) index.php`

Thanks again for all your help!!!
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the settings in Wordpress? Log in to admin and check `Settings/Basics` (or what it is called in English, I'm using a Swedish translation). There you can configure which URL Wordpress is using. If it's set without `www.`, Wordpress will try to redirect.

Comment: Oh man, you're the BEST. That's exactly what I needed to do and everything got fixed. Thanks again man.